# Postman gives me the following error: "error": "no handler found for uri [/megacorp/employee/1] and method [PUT]"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am just starting with Elasticsearch and I have started with adding an index, which works and I can get information about it:

GET http://localhost:9200/megacorp

```
"megacorp": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {},
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "routing": {
                "allocation": {
                    "include": {"_tier_preference": "data_content"
                    }
                }
            },
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "provided_name": "megacorp",
            "creation_date": "1657286196414",
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "uuid": "HbsAAv-mRziSUKGiXPMyPA",
            "version": {
                "created": "8030299"
```

The problem comes when I try to add a document, I get the following error:

PUT http://localhost:9200/megacorp/empoyee/1

"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Smith",
"age": 25,
"about": "I love to go rock climbing",
"interests": ["sports", "music"]

"error": "no handler found for uri [/megacorp/empoyee/1] and method [PUT]"

I think I've done everything right, but it still does not work.

Comment: You are simply firing a PUT request on same `index` which does not have values such as first_name, last_name etc, instead that `index` has values like number of shards, aliases etc . are you sure you want to update the index or update data within it ?

Comment: I want to add a document into the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here, that you are using wrong URL in your request.
According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) you must use use following paths for document index:

```
Request
PUT /<target>/_doc/<_id>

POST /<target>/_doc/

PUT /<target>/_create/<_id>

POST /<target>/_create/<_id>
```

So you are missing `_doc` or `_create` part.

UPDATE:
cURL Example

```
curl -X PUT --location "http://localhost:9200/megacorp/1" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d "{
      \"first_name\": \"John\",
      \"last_name\": \"Smith\",
      \"age\": 25,
      \"about\": \"I love to go rock climbing\",
      \"interests\": [\"sports\", \"music\"]
    }"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints. 
I have tried with the following requests:

http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_doc/1 
and 
http://localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/_create/1 

and the body is unchanged and I still receive the same error:

no handler found for uri [/megacorp/employee/_doc/1] and method [PUT]

If I try only with http://localhost:9200/megacorp/_doc/1 

I get
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parse_exception",
                "reason": "request body is required"
    "status": 400

Comment: remove `employee` from URL. Types were deprecated in 8.x

Comment: I see you did a try without `employee` part and got error ` "reason": "request body is required"`. This means that you are missing payload in request. Try to set header `Content-Type: application/json` in POSTMAN or try to do it via cURL as example. 
`curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/1" 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "user": {
    "id": "elkbee"
  }
}
'
`

Comment: Updated answer with cURL - try in in console pls or convert to postman (you can import cURL https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/importing-and-exporting-data/)

Comment: I already had this header, but I also had some additional, that were automatically putted by Postman. After I removed some of them it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Will recommend you to use Kibana dev tools - this will simplify your life a lot :). And. please accept answer to resolve this topic.

Answer (score 0):

From [elasticsearch 8.x mapping types are removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). You need to use this for indexing the documents

```
http://localhost:9200/megacorp/_doc/1
```